# How to perform multiple actions with one form?

Tags: java, jsp, frames

I have a form that takes in a userID. It is located on a page with 3 frames. How would I open two different .jsp's in the frames after the user submits their ID?

Answer (score 0):

In your `<form/>` Tag use the attribute `target="_parent"` to break up the current frame set. Then in your response you can send a new frameset so that all three frames are reloaded.

**Update to clarify it a little bit:**

`form` tag without `target` attribute:
The user submits the form. The server processes the form data and sends a response, i.e. a welcome page. The browser shows this response page in the same frame.

`form` tag with `target="_parent"`: The user submits the form. Ther server processes the form data and sends a response. The difference here is, that the browser replaces the whole frameset with the server respone. This gives you the chance to update the other frames.

But in this case you have to change the server response. If it is still the welcome page then the browser will show only that page and no other frames.
The server response should be a frameset similar to the original frameset. But you can replace the three frame URLs with different URLs:

Original frameset:

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="login.jsp" name="frame1" />
  <frame src="contentA.jsp" name="frame2" />
  <frame src="contentB.jsp" name="frame3" />
</frameset>
```

As a response to the user login you send a new frameset

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="welcome.jsp" name="frame1" />
  <frame src="contentC.jsp" name="frame2" />
  <frame src="contentD.jsp" name="frame3" />
</frameset>
```

Comment: What do you mean in my response? 

<form name="input" action="index.html" method="get" target="parent">
       <input type="text" name="id" /> 
       <input type="submit" name ="submit"/>
</form>

but how do I change the other frames?

Comment: I tried your method, but now the frameset opens in one of the frames. So now there's 2 different sets of frames open.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. The special target names all starts with an underline. So it has to be `target="_parent"`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Where would I place the second frameset? the 3rd frame contains a value that is created using the form in the URL.

Comment: The frameset from the form submit result should replace the original frameset. You can store some values into the web session while processing the form submit. The JSPs for the frames can later read these values out of the session context. Alternatively you can extend the URLs in the frame's `src` attribute with some GET parameters. Then you don't have to store something into the session. But this is limited to a small amount of data.